# Head of ssh file resource

Tags: ssh, unix

Sort of an odd question, but is there some way that I can operate on remote resources as UNIX files?

E.g. I'm looking for some way to do tasks like the following:

```
head ssh://hostname:/path/to/file.txt
cat http://domain.com/file.html > local-file
```

I strongly suspect that the answer is no.  Any hints in attempts at this sort of thing are also encouraged

Answer (score 1):

Natively, there is no such capability in SSH.

However, you can achieve much the same thing with [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), which lets you mount a remote, SSH-accessible file system and then act on it locally as if it were a local resource.

You could also establish an SSH tunnel to proxy some other method of network sharing, such as NFS, SMB, or CIFS, which would again achieve a similar end result.

Answer (score 0):

For SSH, what you can do is run the command non-interactive on the remote system:

```
ssh hostname "head /path/to/file"
```

This allows allows you to redirect the output into process on your local machine:

```
ssh hostname "cat /path/to/file" | head
```

The `head` here is executed on your local machine.
You can also take local output and redirect it into an SSH session:

```
cat /local/file | ssh hostname "head > /remote/file"
```

This would take the content of your local file, pipe it through the SSH connection into a remotely running head, and write the output of head to a file on the server.

To access HTTP (and HTTPS) files and further process them locally the tool of choice is typically `curl`:

```
curl http://domain.com/file.html > local-file
```

Here `curl` is run locally and fetches the HTML file for you to work with.
It does not allow you to change the remote files though, as this is not a feature of the HTTP protocol.